# Segoe UI Font in non windows systems

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am developing the frontend of a web application and the design requires the use of the Segoe UI font. I used this font for a few text areas but in non Windows systems (Mac OS borwsers, Android, etc) those texts don't render with the Segoe UI font.

After googling this I found that this font is used by Microsoft. My question is. Can just use the font files in the frontend an use @face-font to include the font in the frontend? Or do I need some licence or something like that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't license Segoe UI from Microsoft without direct contact, you can license the mono font from [Ascender Corp](http://www.ascendercorp.com/font/segoe-ui/) who are linked to from Microsoft webpage for Segoe UI, however it is not the same as Segoe UI.

I would suggest [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans) as an alternative to the Segoe UI font, it is quite similar and has much more open licensing for using as webfont (that link is actually to Google's hosted version of the font) - So you could have Segoe as the main font then fall back to Open Sans on non Windows 7+ Systems.

Comment: Thank you. I may end up using another font in systems where Segoe is not used like you said.

Answer (score 4):

Technically you can embed the font through css, but I don't think the license will allow you do do that legally. Couldn't find out right off the bat though - msft's licensing is as always a maze to navigate.

Could you find an alternative font on [Google web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) or [Typekit](https://typekit.com/) and use instad? They all have permissive licenses? (Open Sans is quite similar, for example)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CSS simply call the font in a font stack. It can be the first font or listed second or third. Each device or browser will use the fonts in your list as they are found on the system. If you put a Mac-only font first, Windows systems will default to the second or third font it finds installed.

If you want to host the font yourself, be mindful that some devices will not support certain fonts and you'll still need to list alternative fonts no matter what. Check your analytics to see what types of devices and browsers are visiting. Pick the most popular as your main font and then add fonts for the others in descending order.

There's no guarantee that any font will actually load. There are too many variables and the users can always uninstall fonts or shut off javascript and other nonsense that can drive a web designer crazy.

I use a combination of hosted and installed fonts in most of my sites, especially when design is more critical.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insightful answer!